# Optimising LINQ TO SQL (currently it takes around 2 - 3 minutes) for report module?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-to-sql, query-optimization

I am querying for report module to show a pivot table, some of the columns are dynamic, so i am creating a dictionary object to construct my object, so let say i have 1 user_applications table with around 40k records, and this table also referenced by other tables.

i do this :

```
//masters
            var master_genders = CTX.translate_value_ms.Where(a => a.PSF_type == "SEX").OrderBy(o => o.translate_value_id).ToList();
            var master_edus = CTX.education_lvl_ms.OrderBy(o => o.education_lvl_id).ToList();
            var master_stats = CTX.app_status_ms.OrderBy(o => o.status_order).ToList();
            var master_criteria = CTX.criteria_suggestion_templates.OrderBy(o => o.criteria_suggestion_template_id).ToList();
            //

            //load mapping
            Dictionary<int, int> Gender_Map = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            int start = 0;
            foreach (var m in master_genders)
            {
                Gender_Map.Add(m.translate_value_id, start);
                start++;
            }

            Dictionary<int, int> Edu_Map = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            start = 0;
            foreach (var e in master_edus)
            {
                Edu_Map.Add(e.education_lvl_id, start);
                start++;
            }

            Dictionary<string, int> Stat_Map = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            start = 0;

            var first = master_stats.GroupBy(g => g.status_web).OrderBy(o => o.FirstOrDefault().status_order);

            foreach (var s in first)
            {
                Stat_Map.Add(s.Key, start);
                start++;
            }

            Dictionary<int, int> Criteria_Map = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            start = 0;

            foreach (var m in master_criteria)
            {
                Criteria_Map.Add(m.criteria_suggestion_template_id, start);
                start++;
            }
            //

            var idx = 0;
            var cur_age = 0;
            int int_jobfair = 0;
            int total = 0;

            user_address address_dom = null;
            string key = "";
            bool check = false;
            ReportSubObject obj = null;
            user_edu user_last_edu = null;
            user_test last_test = null;
            criteria_suggestion checkcrit = null;

            var usertest = CTX.user_tests;
            var testcriteria = CTX.criteria_suggestions;

            double total_a = 0;
            double total_b = 0;
            double total_c = 0;
            double total_d = 0;
            double total_e = 0;
            double total_f = 0;

            var addresses = CTX.user_addresses.Where(a => a.address_type == 0).ToList();

            foreach (var itm in apps.ToList())
            {
                var a_begin = DateTime.Now;
                total = 0;
                address_dom = null;
                key = "";
                check = false;
                obj = null;
                user_last_edu = null;
                last_test = null;
                checkcrit = null;

                address_dom = addresses.Where(a => a.user_id == itm.user_id).FirstOrDefault();
                var a_end = DateTime.Now;

                DateTime b_begin = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime b_end = DateTime.Now;

                DateTime c_begin = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime c_end = DateTime.Now;

                DateTime d_begin = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime d_end = DateTime.Now;

                DateTime e_begin = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime e_end = DateTime.Now;

                DateTime f_begin = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime f_end = DateTime.Now;

                b_begin = DateTime.Now;
                int_jobfair = 0;

                if (itm.manager_id != null)
                    int_jobfair = 1;

                key = int_jobfair + " - " + itm.applied_date.Value.Month + " - " + itm.posting.job_id + " - " + itm.posting.location_id + " - " + itm.posting.job_cat_id + " - " + itm.posting.office_cat_id + " - " + (address_dom != null && address_dom.state_id != null ? address_dom.state_id.ToString() : "0");

                check = SubmissionObj.ContainsKey(key);

                if (!check)
                {
                    obj = new ReportSubObject();
                    obj.Source = (itm.manager_id != null ? "Job Fair" : "Website");
                    obj.Job = myTI.ToTitleCase(itm.posting.job_m.PSF_Desc.ToLower());
                    obj.Location = myTI.ToTitleCase(itm.posting.job_location_m.PSF_Desc.ToLower());
                    obj.JobCat = myTI.ToTitleCase(itm.posting.job_category_m.PSF_Desc.ToLower());
                    obj.OfficeCat = myTI.ToTitleCase(itm.posting.office_category_m.PSF_Desc.ToLower());
                    obj.ApplyProv = (address_dom != null && address_dom.state_id != null ? address_dom.state_m.state_desc : "");


                    obj.from = (DateTime)itm.applied_date;

                    obj.Total = total += 1;

                    #region gender

                    obj.KeyPairGender = new List<int>();
                    master_genders.ForEach(b => obj.KeyPairGender.Add(0));

                    if (itm.user_list.gender_id != null)
                    {
                        idx = Gender_Map[(int)itm.user_list.gender_id];

                        //obj.KeyPairGender[idx] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(obj.KeyPairGender[idx].Key, obj.KeyPairGender[idx].Value + 1);
                        obj.KeyPairGender[idx] += 1;
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region edu

                    obj.KeyPairEdu = new List<int>();
                    master_edus.ForEach(b => obj.KeyPairEdu.Add(0));

                    user_last_edu = itm.user_list.user_edus.OrderByDescending(o => o.edu_lvl_id).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user_last_edu != null)
                    {
                        idx = Edu_Map[(int)user_last_edu.edu_lvl_id];
                        obj.KeyPairEdu[idx] += 1;
                    }
                    #endregion

                    b_end = DateTime.Now;

                    c_begin = DateTime.Now;
                    #region Age
                    obj.AgeRange = new int[5];
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        obj.AgeRange[i] = 0;
                    }

                    cur_age = itm.applied_date.Value.Year - itm.user_list.birthday.Value.Year;
                    if (itm.user_list.birthday > ((DateTime)itm.applied_date).AddYears(-cur_age)) cur_age--;

                    if (cur_age >= 18 && cur_age <= 21)
                        obj.AgeRange[0] += 1;
                    else if (cur_age >= 22 && cur_age <= 24)
                        obj.AgeRange[1] += 1;
                    else if (cur_age >= 25 && cur_age <= 27)
                        obj.AgeRange[2] += 1;
                    else if (cur_age >= 28 && cur_age <= 30)
                        obj.AgeRange[3] += 1;
                    else if (cur_age > 30)
                        obj.AgeRange[4] += 1;

                    #endregion

                    #region appstatus

                    obj.KeyPairAppStat = new List<int>();
                    foreach (var loop in first)
                    {
                        obj.KeyPairAppStat.Add(0);
                    }

                    if (itm.app_status_id != null)
                    {
                        idx = Stat_Map[itm.app_status_m.status_web];

                        obj.KeyPairAppStat[idx] += 1;
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region criteria

                    obj.KeyPairCriteria = new List<int>();
                    master_criteria.ForEach(b => obj.KeyPairCriteria.Add(0));

                    if (itm.online_test_id != null)
                    {
                        last_test = usertest.Where(a => a.user_id == itm.user_id && a.package_id == itm.online_test.package_id).OrderByDescending(o => o.date_score).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (last_test != null)
                        {
                            if (last_test.total_score != null)
                            {
                                checkcrit = testcriteria.Where(a => a.package_id == last_test.package_id &&
                                                                                    (last_test.total_score >= a.score_from && last_test.total_score <= a.score_to)
                                                                              ).FirstOrDefault();
                                if (checkcrit != null)
                                {
                                    idx = Criteria_Map[(int)checkcrit.criteria_opt_id];

                                    obj.KeyPairCriteria[idx] += 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion

                    SubmissionObj.Add(key, obj);

                    c_end = DateTime.Now;
                }
                else
                {
                    d_begin = DateTime.Now;

                    var tmp = SubmissionObj[key];

                    tmp.Total++;

                    if (tmp.to < itm.applied_date)
                        tmp.to = (DateTime)itm.applied_date;

                    #region gender
                    if (itm.user_list.gender_id != null)
                    {
                        idx = Gender_Map[(int)itm.user_list.gender_id];
                        tmp.KeyPairGender[idx] += 1;
                    }
                    #endregion
                    d_end = DateTime.Now;

                    e_begin = DateTime.Now;
                    #region edu
                    user_last_edu = itm.user_list.user_edus.OrderByDescending(o => o.edu_lvl_id).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user_last_edu != null)
                    {
                        idx = Edu_Map[(int)user_last_edu.edu_lvl_id];
                        tmp.KeyPairEdu[idx] += 1;
                    }
                    #endregion




                    #region age
                    cur_age = itm.applied_date.Value.Year - itm.user_list.birthday.Value.Year;
                    if (itm.user_list.birthday > ((DateTime)itm.applied_date).AddYears(-cur_age)) cur_age--;

                    if (cur_age >= 18 && cur_age <= 21)
                        tmp.AgeRange[0] += 1;
                    else if (cur_age >= 22 && cur_age <= 24)
                        tmp.AgeRange[1] += 1;
                    else if (cur_age >= 25 && cur_age <= 27)
                        tmp.AgeRange[2] += 1;
                    else if (cur_age >= 28 && cur_age <= 30)
                        tmp.AgeRange[3] += 1;
                    else if (cur_age > 30)
                        tmp.AgeRange[4] += 1;
                    #endregion

                    #region appstatus
                    if (itm.app_status_id != null)
                    {
                        idx = Stat_Map[itm.app_status_m.status_web];

                        tmp.KeyPairAppStat[idx] += 1;
                    }
                    #endregion

                    e_end = DateTime.Now;

                    f_begin = DateTime.Now;

                    #region criteria
                    if (itm.online_test_id != null)
                    {
                        last_test = usertest.Where(a => a.user_id == itm.user_id && a.package_id == itm.online_test.package_id).OrderByDescending(o => o.date_score).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (last_test != null)
                        {
                            if (last_test.date_score != null)
                            {
                                checkcrit = testcriteria.Where(a => a.package_id == last_test.package_id &&
                                                                                    (last_test.total_score >= a.score_from && last_test.total_score <= a.score_to)
                                                                              ).FirstOrDefault();
                                if (checkcrit != null)
                                {
                                    idx = Criteria_Map[(int)checkcrit.criteria_opt_id];

                                    tmp.KeyPairCriteria[idx] += 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion
                    f_end = DateTime.Now;

                }

                total_a += (a_end - a_begin).TotalSeconds;
                total_b += (b_end - b_begin).TotalSeconds;
                total_c += (c_end - c_begin).TotalSeconds;
                total_d += (d_end - d_begin).TotalSeconds;
                total_e += (e_end - e_begin).TotalSeconds;
                total_f += (f_end - f_begin).TotalSeconds;
            }
```

as u notice in above code, i have a few sub queries inside foreach loop, and i put a few variables to count which part took most time in seconds, and its true that the sub queries part took the longest, overall it took around 2 minutes for those codes to be executed, so i tried to move all sub queries outside foreach loop, i do this :

```
     var customapp = apps.Select(x => new
            {
                dom_address = x.user_list.user_addresses.Where(a => a.address_type == 0).FirstOrDefault(),
                manager_id = x.manager_id,
                applied_date = x.applied_date,

                job_id = x.posting.job_id,
                job_desc = x.posting.job_m.PSF_Desc,

                location_id = x.posting.location_id,
                loc_desc = x.posting.job_location_m.PSF_Desc,

                job_cat_id = x.posting.job_cat_id,
                job_cat_desc = x.posting.job_category_m.PSF_Desc,

                office_cat_id = x.posting.office_cat_id,
                office_cat_desc = x.posting.office_category_m.PSF_Desc,

                gender_id = x.user_list.gender_id,
                birthday = x.user_list.birthday,

                edu = x.user_list.user_edus.OrderByDescending(o => o.edu_lvl_id).FirstOrDefault(),

                status_PSF_id = x.app_status_id,
                status_from_PSF = x.app_status_m.status_web,

                online_test_id = x.online_test_id,

                last_test = x.user_tests.Where(a => a.user_id == x.user_id && a.package_id == x.online_test.package_id).OrderByDescending(o => o.date_score).FirstOrDefault()
            });


            DateTime end_z = DateTime.Now;

            double total_z = (end_z - begin_z).TotalSeconds;

            foreach (var itm in customapp.ToList())
            {
                //logic to construct my dictionary as before, but without sub queries.
             }
```

the second code it does not improve the speed, instead it took longer than previous one, can u tell me what can i do to optimize my query?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are doing extra db calls for each subquery for each application.

This is how you can avoid it:

```
// Plain query, not doing subqueries. Unfortunately brings extra rows in memory.
var q =
    from app in ctx.Applications
    join s in ctx.SubObjectsOne on app.Id equals s.AppId into joinedSubObjectOne
    from subObjectOne in joinedSubObjectOne.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where subObjectOne.SomeProperty == 0 // additional sub object criteria
    select new { app, subObjectOne };

var l = q.ToList();

// From now on objects are materialized, doing the rest in memory:
var translated =
    from i in l
    group i by i.app.Id into g
    select new
    {
        app = g.First().app,

        // This is expensive too, but not doing separate db requests.
        SubObjectOneByMaxProperty = g.Select(i => i.subObjectOne).OrderByDescending(s => s.SomeOrder).FirstOrDefault()
    };

var translatedList = translated.ToList();
```

You can use this approach if your sub-object counts are not very high.

If you can figure out how to compute a needed value using sql aggregates, it would be even better. For example,
subObjects.Where(..).OrderByDescencing(..).First(..) would turn into subObjects.Max(s=>s.SomeProp), if you need just a max value, not an entire object. It would compute directly in db without extra db calls.

And an even better approach would be to avoid computations at the time of building a report. You can denormalize your data slightly, for example - store the ids of needed objects in an aggregation table, and update the table when related data changes:

```
table aggregated_data(app_id, address_id, max_edu_lvl_id, max_score_test_id)
```

Comment: your first approach, i think that might work, but my sub objects are dynamic, so the count keep increasing, the count is around 11k for now.